# Background of highlighting on "How to Answer" covers text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On the [How to Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) page the yellow highlight background covers the text above:

[image]

Tested on Google Chrome 13.

Comment: Could you tell me please where is this page? I know I saw it some time ago, when I joined the community, but I wanted to review it today, and I can't find it! It is rather strange, that you have a "How to ask a question" in the FAQ, but "How to Answer" is not there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.